# How to avoid hitting memory ceiling when calculating a churn curve?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm calculating the churn curve for 24 month data.
A given row represents one person with one product for one month of their membership.

E.g. if a person had a product for 12 months he is responsible for 12 rows labeled 0 through 11.

As of right now I calculate two shares and divide them with each other to get one minus the rate of churn for a given month.

This is calculated the following way:

```
Andel1 = 
    var Maxstart = MAX(SqlData[StartOpret])
            var Minstart = CALCULATE(DATEADD(SqlData[StartOpret],-5,MONTH),SqlData[StartOpret]=Maxstart)
return
            CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(SqlData),SqlData[Binary]=0,SqlData[Start+periode] <=Maxstart,SqlData[Start+periode]>=Minstart)
```

```
Andel2 = 
            var Maxdate = MAX(SqlData[StartOpret])
            var Maxstart = CALCULATE(DATEADD(SqlData[StartOpret],0,MONTH),SqlData[StartOpret]=Maxdate)
            var Minstart = CALCULATE(DATEADD(SqlData[StartOpret],-5,MONTH),SqlData[StartOpret]=Maxdate)
return
            CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(SqlData),SqlData[Binary]=1,SqlData[Start+periode] <=Maxstart,SqlData[Start+periode]>=Minstart)
```

```
Fremskriv = DIVIDE([Andel1],[Andel2],1)
```

In the context of the churn months this returns what is expected:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iX0IM.png

To plot the churn curve I would need to calculate how many are still present after a number of months. This is attempted by taking the product of all the prior values of "Fremskriv".

```
Samlet_andel = 
VAR Maks = MAX(SqlData[antal_kor])
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    PRODUCTX(SUMMARIZE(
            SqlData,
            SqlData[antal_kor],
            "Prod", [Fremskriv]),
            [Prod]),
        ALLEXCEPT(SqlData,SqlData[antal_kor]),SqlData[antal_kor] <= Maks)
```

This claims lack of memory for the operation, and is in general really slow if I only calculate the value for a given churn month.

I'm at a loss, all help appreciated :)

Thank you in advance